# primevue InputMask or Password component for secret like SSN

Tags: vuejs3, primevue

I am trying to implement an input for SSN with the ability to hide/mask the input with (*) and be able to read it using the "[eye icon](https://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/eye-hide)".
I had two options and both are limited in some form.
Option 1: [InputMask](https://primevue.org/inputmask/) does not have the ability to hide the input value.
Option 2: [Password](https://primevue.org/password/) does not have masking feature where I can provide a pattern like XXX-XX-XXXX
Is there a simple way to implement this?